# powershell search contents of text file very slower?

Tags: powershell

```
## Create new text file based on the date of today
#mu2_20140429040401
$mu = "c:\temp\test\mu2_"
$tag = "c:\temp\test\tag_"
$Date = Get-Date
$DateStr = $Date.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmm")
$fname_mu = $mu + $DateStr + "01.txt"
$fname_tag = $tag + $DateStr + "01.txt"
$src = "c:\temp\test\mt_point.txt"
$dstDir = "C:\temp\test\test\"
$Location = "C:\temp\test\CompositeID.txt"
# Delete previous output files
Remove-Item -Path "$dstDir\*"#
$inData =New-Object -TypeName System.IO.StreamReader -ArgumentList $src
$header = $inData.ReadLine() 
$header1=$inData.ReadLine() 
$header2=$inData.ReadLine() 
$header3=$inData.ReadLine() 
$header4=$inData.ReadLine() 
$header5=$inData.ReadLine() 
$header6=$inData.ReadLine() 
$header7=$inData.ReadLine() 
$header8=$inData.ReadLine() 
$header9=$inData.ReadLine() 
$header10=$inData.ReadLine() 
$header11=$inData.ReadLine() 
$header12=$inData.ReadLine() 
$header13=$inData.ReadLine() 
$header14=$inData.ReadLine() 
$header15=$inData.ReadLine() 

$currentFile = ""
while ($line = $inData.ReadLine())
{  
#echo $line  
$s_point =$line -split ","
#echo $newFile 
$s_point=$s_point -replace ''''
$point_ID=$s_point[2]+"."+$s_point[3]+"."+$s_point[4]+"."+$s_point[5]
#echo $point_ID
$Sel = Select-String  -pattern $point_ID -path $Location 
#echo $Sel
        $tp_point_stirng= $Sel-split ";"
        $tp_point_no=$tp_point_stirng[0]-split ":"
        $tp_point=$tp_point_no[3]-split ","
        if($point_ID  -eq $tp_point_stirng[1])
   {
    if($s_point[6]-eq "T")
    {
        $Nis_point="!1!"+$tp_point[1]+"!"+$s_point[2]+ "!"+$tp_point_stirng[7]+"!0!SI!!"+$s_point[7]+"!!!!"+ $s_point[8]+"!"
       # $Nis_point | out-file -filepath $fname_tag -Append 
      # $stream =New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter ($fname_tag,"True",[System.Text.Encoding]::Ascii)
      # $stream.WriteLine($Nis_point)
      # $stream.close()

    }
    }

}
```

the use " Select-String  -pattern $point_ID -path $Location " very slower,do you have any search content text file in powershell faster?

example :

a.text file

3,44545;apa.ftp.dfv.de;fdfd;aaa;ee;

2,45433;bb.tt.uu.cc;dddd;wwww;tt;

search the line object is apa.ftp.dfv.de,if match then output the line;

3,44545;apa.ftp.dfv.de;fdfd;aaa;ee;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$searchTerm = 'apa.ftp.dfv.de'
Get-Content .\textfile.txt | Where-Object {$_ like "*$($searchTerm)*"}
```